# Crear listas de datos de manera dinámica

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de datos y quiero crear sublistas en función de un valor variable. Por ejemplo, tengo una lista con 21 valores y el valor variable vale 3.

```
myvals = [21,19,29,33,33,35,42,72,52,78,127,90,150,100,83,63,60,49,32,0,0]
div = 3
```

La cosa es que me gustaría crear X listas donde el reparto fuera consecutivo, según el valor de división. Según el ejemplo anterior, 3 listas donde el 21 va a la primera lista, 19 a la segunda, 29 a la tercera y volver a empezar, 33 a la primera... Quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
e1 = [21,33,42,78,150,63,32]
e2 = [19,33,72,127,100,60,0]
e3 = [29,35,52,90,83,49,0]
```

¿Hay alguna manera de crear estas listas? ¿O en su defecto que yo pueda seleccionar los valores de mi lista inicial según el criterio mencionado?

Intento hacerlo a base de bucles pero no consigo nada correcto y pienso que una clase podría ser una opción pero tampoco me aclaro mucho.

¡Gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Publica el código y los resultados obtenidos hasta ahora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1 opción, más simple

Simplemente agregue cada valor a una lista correcta:

```py
myvals = [21,19,29,33,33,35,42,72,52,78,127,90,150,100,83,63,60,49,32,0,0]
div = 3

results = [[] for _ in range(div)]

for i, valor in enumerate(myvals):
    results[i % div].append(valor)

for lst in results:
    print(lst)
```

## 2 opción, más pequeño

El mismo algoritmo, pero usando iteradores:

```py
myvals = [21,19,29,33,33,35,42,72,52,78,127,90,150,100,83,63,60,49,32,0,0]
div = 3

results = [myvals[i::div] for i in range(div)]

for lst in results:
    print(lst)
```